# How to determine PCI slot for failing GPU

Tags: graphics-card

I have six GPUs installed and 1 of them is having driver issues. When I open the category "**Display Adapters**" in the Device Manager, the faulty GPU shows a yellow exclamation sign in the corner and the properties of this card show that it is connected to **PCI bus 3**.

How can I find out which GPU is physically connected to **PCI bus 3**? So that I can replace the GPU with another one, rather than removing all of them one by one.

Comment: You are going to have to determine which PCI-e slot is PCI Bus 1 and extrapolate which one is 3.

Comment: but how? thats what i need to know

Comment: You pull one of the cards, start the computer, determine which bus the card was connected to.

Comment: You ask the tech support of the motherboard manufacturer. Or just download the manual for the mobo and figure it out yourself.

Comment: ill have a look, thx for ur guidance

Comment: I tried a everything but its very hard to reach to exact location coz whenever i change my GPU positions the bus location changes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard manual generally shows diagrams of which slot is which number.  It's also usually written onto the motherboard, but may be very small letters and you have hardware in the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general approach to this, as far as I know.

The motherboard manual may indicate how bus-numbers used in Windows Device Manager correspond to the physical slots on the motherboard, but this is very rarely the case. (I have only seen this on some server-grade motherboards.)

It is even possible that these bus-numbers are assigned dynamically and shift depending on bios version/configuration, number of cards installed and OS used. (Quite common in consumer grade equipment.)

If you can get the GPU/card serial number from the information shown in Windows (device manager or WMIC), you may be able to identify the correct GPU card by the corresponding serial-number label on the card itself, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager>display adapters, disable the non working device. Shut down the PC then disconnect power of first GPU and start the pc, go to device manager>display adapters and see if the disabled device is showing there or not. If not showing then that removed GPU is your damaged GPU, if still showing in device manager>display adapters then shut down your pc and connect the first GPU and disconnect power of the next GPU. Start pc, check device manager>display adapters. Keep repeating this till you find your damaged GPU.

Answer (score -1):

So if nobody found an answer, I would like suggest to divide GPUs by *.inf-files.
E.g. you have a mobo with 7 pci-e slots with 7 GPUs inside:
unpack the driver files and copy the main inf-file 7 times - for example slot1.inf, slot2.inf and so on.
Inside the every inf-file give a name to graphic card - it was NVidia Ti4200? Add to the name Ti4200_Slot1, to the second card’s inf-file Nvidia_Riva_Slot2, NVidia_GEFORCE_Slot3, NVidia_Slot4 and so on.
Then just instal one by one appropriate driver by forcing to use the specific inf-file.